# Unhandled exception: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3852: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: mysql

So I tried to download this dataset from kaggle and when I try to import it shows the following error. [Error Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Vlk.png)

I opened in Excel and even notebook and saved as UTF-8 but still faced an error. Does this mean this dataset can only be opened with python? I have not yet studied python but wanted do a few queries with SQL and visualizations for my project.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vardan95ghazaryan/top-250-football-transfers-from-2000-to-2018

Answer (score 1):

The character set must be specified in multiple places:

- The client
- The table definition (or defaulted from the database)

and maybe other places.

For further discussion, please show the line that is in question, plus hex of that line, plus what you expect the line to day.

**Kaggle**

I found this in that download; there are doubtless other issues:

```
Diego Tristán
```

The `á` character in that name is encoded as hex E1, implying that it is one of these encodings:  cp1250, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5.  (It is likely to be latin1.)

Your Workbench setup was (apparently) configured to *assume* that any data coming at it would be `UTF-8`.  When it saw the E1, it croaked because that is not valid UTF-8.

Find out how you can configure "imports".  It should allow you to change the "character set"; change that to "latin1".  Then try the import again.

Meanwhile, complain to Kaggle that UTF-8 is becoming the de facto standard and they should change their data to that encoding.

You say you "saved as UTF-8", if so, can you provide me with *that* file.  I'll do a similar analysis.

Comment: Hi,

This is prior to inputting any line. I tried to upload the dataset (downloaded from Kaggle) via the import wizard but faced this error even before selecting the coloumns type. 

Hence I am unable to reproduce any line of code.

Comment: That "import" had to connect to the database and its input file probably has something setting the charset in it.  Look at the beginning of the file.  Look at the configuration of the wizard.

Comment: I don't get it. I just open a brand new connection, clean slate on mysql. Created a new schema and just select import wizard without having any limitations. Works well with other dataset meant for SQL found on kaggle. Sorry if I do not understand your answer well enough.

Comment: The download appears to be encoded as latin1, not UTF-8.

Comment: I tried opening in excel/notepad and saving in UTF-8, however when i try re-upload it still does not work. Is there something I do wrong and if yes, what should I google to make sure I get the right answer? Sorry for the late response always

Answer (score 0):

The character is present in the file which prevents loading of that data in SQL.

- The data can be cleaned by forming a column near by every column and
  cleaning the data using Excel formula **=CLEAN(D1)** *(Assuming the
  cell with data starts in D1)* and apply it to the entire column by
  clicking at the bottom of the cell.
- Then copy the entire column which
  was cleaned by the previous formula and paste special in the same
  column with only values *(To prevent the deletion of the column when
  the reference column is deleted)*.
- Delete the original column.

This helps get rid of all the hidden 0x81 characters in the Excel file.